# WPF checkbox IsChecked binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, binding

I have this problem, that my checkbox IsChecked property binding is not working. I googled, but people say it shoudl TwoWay binding which is what I am using.

Here is my code:

```
 <CheckBox Name="ckC" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           IsChecked="{Binding Path=LSMChannelEnable[2],
                               Mode=TwoWay,
                               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Here is the C# code behind it:

```
public bool[] LSMChannelEnable
{
    get
    {
        return this._liveImage.LSMChannelEnable;
    }
    set
    {
        this._liveImage.LSMChannelEnable = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("LSMChannelEnable");
        OnPropertyChanged("EnableChannelCount");
        OnPropertyChanged("LSMChannel");
    }
}
```

Any pointers are highly appreciated,

Comment: As a side-note, the WPF Checkbox is already two-way binding by default.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because you are binding to an array. Pull the property out that you want to bind to a separate property.

Xaml:

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=ButtonEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Code:

```
public bool ButtonEnabled
{
    get { return this._liveImage.LSMChannelEnable[2]; }
    set { this._liveImage.LSMChannelEnable[2] = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("ButtonEnabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean "public bool ButtonEnabled" ?

Comment: You might want to fire "OnPropertyChanged("ButtonEnabled")" also in the setter of "public bool[] LSMChannelEnable". Otherwise, if you are going to assign a different array to LSMChannelEnable, a possibly changed bool value would not be reflected by the button state.

Comment: @elgozo You're right if the array is kept. Generally I wouldn't recommend storing all of the data in an array. It's better to have single properties

Comment: Thanks! It certainly helps!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
```

The property generated by the compiler when using an indexer.
See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xtof/archive/2007/09/28/binding-to-indexers.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! But I feel upstairs easier to understand.